# How to unproxy LockerService wrapped data for debugging via console.log()?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, locker-service, proxy

In Lightning Components I love to use console.log() to get an understanding what is happening. Often there is data shown as "Proxy{}", which looks in the console like this

[image]

I KNOW that there is fine data in there and I can access all fields of the loaded SObject in JS. But only in console log it gets uglified and crippeled - which is a pain to read an to debug.

I think @sfdcfox told me in the context of an other question, that this is LockerService-footprint... for sure it's a security feature - but actually it's an obstacle for me.

A good reproduction is to have an SObject loaded by APEX and stored into an attribute:

```
<aura:attribute name="MySObject" type="SObject" default="{}" />
```

In the apex callback I simply write the attribute

```
cmp.get("v.MySObject",apexResult.MySObject);
```

and output it then via:

```
console.log( cmp.get("v.MySObject") );
```

now dumping the apexResult.MySObject directly looks in the way I would like

[image]

Is there an easy way to nested-recursively unproxy such data and dump it to the console?

Not only attributes are affected. Also cmp.find()-results and many other things, too. So please see that only as an example - I'm looking for a general unproxy solution to dump "anything" quick and dirty to the console for inspection. Is there a trick?

Comment: I'm going to experiment with a chrome devtools extension and call it "unproxify" https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools. It will be able to use the below solutions to "inspect" any object

Answer (score 5):

We often use this hack:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myProxy)));
```

It's not perfect, and I doubt it's supported, but it works surprisingly well in a variety of scenarios.

While I haven't used it myself, you might wish to explore [these options](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/debug_intro.htm):

- **[Enable Debug Mode for Lightning Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_debug_mode.htm)**

  > Enable debug mode to make it easier to debug JavaScript code from Lightning components. Only enable debug mode for users who are actively debugging JavaScript. Salesforce is slower for users who have debug mode enabled.
- **[Salesforce Lightning Inspector Chrome Extension](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/inspector_intro.htm)**

  > The Salesforce Lightning Inspector is a Google Chrome DevTools extension that enables you to navigate the component tree, inspect component attributes, and profile component performance. The extension also helps you to understand the sequence of event firing and handling.

Comment: Purging comments to remove clutter. I don't think they added much to this conversation.

Comment: One example where it does not work: I'm using jquery to obtain a DOM element which gets proxied. Now the jquery result seems to have circular references and i get only TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Answer (score 3):

This is my way ( used for much more than just debugging purpose )

- Define a function cleanLsObjHlp in a root component helper

  ```
  cleanLsObjHlp: function (LSObj) {
      if (LSObj == null)
          return null ;
      var CleanedObj = (Array.isArray(LSObj) ? [] : {});
      for (var property in LSObj) {
          if (LSObj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
              // null
              if (LSObj[property] == null )
                  CleanedObj[property] = null ;
              // undefined
              else  if  (LSObj[property] === undefined )
                  CleanedObj[property] = undefined ;
              // Object
                  else if (typeof (LSObj[property]) === "object")
                      CleanedObj[property] = this.cleanLsObjHlp(LSObj[property]);
              // Array
                      else if (Array.isArray(LSObj[property]))
                      {
                          var CleanedArray = [];
                          for ( var i = 0; i < LSObj[property].length ; i++)
                          {
                              var ArrCleanObj = this.cleanLsObjHlp(LSObj[property][i]);
                              CleanedArray.push(ArrCleanObj);
                          }
                          CleanedObj[property] = CleanedArray;
                      }
              // Basic prop
                          else
                              CleanedObj[property] = LSObj[property];
          }
      }
      return CleanedObj;
  },
  ```
- Call it when you need to 'unproxy' a proxyfied object or array( it will obviously keep only properties, and not methods )

  ```
  console.log(helper.cleanLsObjHlp(myObjOrArray));
  ```

Comment: Could you clean up the naming? What is `LS`?  What does `Hlp` have to do with anything?

Comment: Dear @AdrianLarson : LS ? what could it be when we are discussing about Locker Service ? I really don't know ^^ And the Hlp is just a naming norm to differentiate controller methods from helper methods :)

Comment: People shouldn't have to guess. A well written name should be obvious to anyone who reads it.

Comment: with the JSON.parse-stringify approach I got issues with circular structures and getting this error: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON. Is your solution covering that case?

Comment: @AdrianLarson > Not because you didn't guess that no one would guess. And any coder not liking the methods name can obviously change it with a single search/replace, so i think that you could spare your keyboard's health when it is to write such comments :)

Comment: @UweHeim > We don't have circular objects... so i'm afraid I can't answer your question, sorry :/ But i think by adding a max depth, it could be easily doable

Comment: RE: circular references: this helped with a simple enough tree structure that had one property named `parent` that was causing the circular reference. Modified it to say `if ('parent' != property && LSObj.hasOwnProperty(property))` did the trick for me. For non-circular structures I typically use the `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...))` trick.

Answer (score 1):

My current workaround instead of doing this

```
console.log( cmp.get("v.MySObject") );
```

is currently mangle it through JSON

```
console.log( JSON.parse( JSON.stringify(  cmp.get("v.MySObject") ) ) );
```

But I'm not sure, if ANY complex and nested structure will be 100% translated.

Comment: The only potential downside is that if there are circular structures, you'll get an exception.

Comment: @sfdcfox exactly! after getting a proxied DOM elements via $('.myClass') I only get: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON - did you find an easy way to onproxy circular structures? This would help me so much...